# How does opengl know which vertices belong together and make a face?

Tags: opengl, 3d

Maybe this is a very basic question but how does OpenGL know which 3 vertices make a face if it's not specified? How to find them from normals?

Comment: If you're using an index buffer 3 successive indices form a face. http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-9-vbo-indexing/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you tell it with an index buffer, or you submit the vertices in the order you would like them to be triangulated (which depends on the type of primitive being drawn ex. GL_TRIANGLES​ vs GL_TRIANGLE_FAN).

Say you have the following vertices for two triangles that create a quad:

```
V3 - - - - - V2
-         -  -
-     -      -
- -          -
V0 - - - - - V1
```

The respective vertex and index arrays for the two triangles would be:

```
GLfloat vertices[4][3] = { v0, v1, v2, v3 };
GLfloat indices[6] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 };
```

You could also simply submit the vertex arrays without an index buffer as:

```
GLfloat vertices[6][3] = { v0, v1, v2, v0, v2, v3 };
```

Here is a great link that goes into more detail: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-9-vbo-indexing/